# Placing items next to each other horizontally HTML

Tags: html, css

Ok, here is how it is set up as of yet.

```
  **<h2>Data Search</h2>**
  <p>This tool does this and that</p>
  <p>To begin your search, do this.
  </p>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
  <h1>Data Search</h1><a name="ds"></a>
  </div>
```

I need to place a button directly to the right of the section with ** before and after it (or line 1). This will be the one and only time I need to do this and so that is why I have not made edits to the .css. Is there a HTML-based solution for this?

I have tried float-right but can't seem to figure out where I would place it in here.

Comment: There is no bold because it formatted it as code in the example you gave.  Your going to need to provide the css for the classes also.

Comment: <h1>Data Search <a href="#">Some text</a></h1> - you can do in this way

Comment: @MarcusStratu, can you submit that as answer so that you can get reputation points. That works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The < h1 > to < h6 > tags are used to define HTML headings. - "this is
>   not a bold"

```
<h1>Data Search <a href="#">Some text</a></h1>
```

For `bold` you can use `<b>` or `<strong>` tag

Comment: I fail to understand how this is the accepted answer to the question.. but maybe I just misunderstood the question in the first place!

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Seems like we have a newbie here, which call <h1> as bold, and he want to arrange link in one line with title.

Comment: But the question is with regards to placing a button right after the header element and has nothing to do with bolding text?

Comment: He only changed tags. The original question is still referring to the `<h2>` element not the `<h1>` element.

Comment: omg sir, it is already clear that you can do the same and with <h2>

Answer (score 2):

You can just place the `button` inside the `h2` tag.

```html
<h2>Data Search
<button>
Button
</button>
</h2>
  <p>This tool does this and that</p>
  <p>To begin your search, do this.
  </p>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
  <h1>Data Search</h1><a name="ds"></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for buttons on the left side and right side. Exactly what you want and described in your question. It is best practice to do your styling in CSS.

HTML

```
<div class="button">
<button type="button">Hello</button>
<h2 class="h2">Data Search</h2>
<button type="button">Bye</button>
</div>

  <p>This tool does this and that</p>
  <p>To begin your search, do this.
  </p>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
  <h1>Data Search</h1><a name="ds"></a>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.button{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.h2{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

give the container holding all the elements position: relative;

then add the button in that container anywhere you want.
Just give the button the following css.

```
button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

make right the proper measurement to make it directly beside the Header tag element.

Comment: Would probably be better to make use of the many layout tools available, such as the table html element or css flexbox (or css grid, if you don't care about older browsers).

Comment: flex maybe, table layouts are so 1999